# An internal error occurred during: "Loading referenced grammars". eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, android-layout

An internal error occurred during: "Loading referenced grammars".
java.lang.AbstractMethodError

This is the error I am getting in eclipse while adding or deleting any line in android XML file.

In my (Windows/Preferences/XML/XML Catalog) shows "An error has occurred when creating this preference page."

Also tried (Windows/Preferences/XML/XML Files/Validation) in Validating files No grammar specified(Ignore) and Missing root element (Ignore)

Please help me it is getting annoying while writing XML files for android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah this was very annoying info popup...

Well I just (Help/Check for updates) and install all updates and it works for me.